# Placing php ,html, php in one line

Tags: php, wordpress

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong in my code? Every time I try, I receive

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.'

```
<?php if ( is_woocommerce()){ '<a href="' . home_url(); . '">Home</a>' 
        } else { '<a href="' . home_url('/shop/'); . '">My Shop</a>' 
 }?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here you go:**

```
<?php 
    if (is_woocommerce())
    { 
        echo '<a href="' . home_url() . '">Home</a>';
    } 
    else 
    { 
        echo '<a href="' . home_url('/shop/') . '">My Shop</a>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: So in other words I forgot the echos :) .I knew I was close. Thank you !

Comment: @CosminP Well two issues, the `echo`s but also note you have `;` after your call to `home_url()` which is no good as well. Good luck on your project.